# $15 [\tan 2\theta + \sin 2\theta] + 8 = 0$ if ...

Tags: trigonometry

> **QUESTION**: $15[\tan 2\theta + \sin 2\theta] + 8 = 0$ if...
>    (a) $\tan\theta = \frac{1}{2}$
>    (b) $\sin\theta = \frac{1}{4}$
>    (c) $\tan\theta = 2$
>    (d) $\cos\theta = \frac{1}{5}$

What I have tried:
$$\tan2\theta + \sin2\theta = -\frac{8}{15}$$
$$\frac{2\tan\theta}{1-\tan^2\theta} + \frac{2\tan\theta}{1+\tan^2\theta} = -\frac{8}{15}$$

From here onwards, I am stuck and do not know how to continue. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: Try substituting the given values...

Comment: But i want to know the actual method to solve this question

Answer (score 2):

From the final equation you gave, one gets
$$\frac{4\tan\theta}{1-\tan^4\theta} = -\frac{8}{15} \quad\Rightarrow\quad
8\tan^4\theta - 60\tan\theta -8=0.$$
This quartic factors as $4(\tan\theta-2)(2\tan^3\theta + 4\tan^2\theta + 8\tan\theta + 1)$.
This shows that (c) is a solution while (a) is not. To see that (b) and (d) are not solutions, I think you'll have to substitute the appropriate values of $\tan\theta$ into the cubic.

Comment: I need to learn to type faster.  +1.